# I am getting wrong frame size of UIVIEW

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, frame

I have a frame that I set inside the UIVIEW using nib. When I trying to get the size of an inside view I am getting the wrong width size.

Screen Width is 320 for iPhone SE/5S

the frame width size should be 320 but I am getting 414.

**bottomView.frame.size.width**

Comment: Is autolayout not working?

Comment: In which method do you try to get the width?

Comment: add more details.

Comment: You have to check view size after all constraints apply to view. *viewDidAppear* - Notifies the view controller that its view was added to a view hierarchy. So, you have to check frame inside *viewDidAppear*. Second option check size using delay.

Comment: You can get correct size in draw method. Or you can use

UIScreen.main.bounds.size

to get the full screen size

Comment: The best way you can go about this is to use `draw` method , also if u could add a little more code we could give a better insight ,or try overriding `layOutSubViews`  . I think you should pay more attention to `setLayoutIfNeeded` and `layOutIfNeeded` . Show us what you have done